# Check if Ajax returns true, another function to run

Tags: ajax

I have a function with Ajax call. If it returns true, another function with another Ajax should be run. But in my case first function returns true but the second function doesn't run. How to do that?
If I remove this: `if(checkIfCompleted()) {` from the second function, it's working. But I have to check if first function returns true.
My code is:

```js
function checkIfCompleted() {
 $.ajax(
 {
  url: Base_URL + "/offers/" + 'checkIfQuoteIsComplete',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
   "offer_id": offer_id                
  },

  success: function (data) {
   if(data === 'notcompleted') {
    $("#NotCompleteQuotes").modal(); 
    return false;
   } else {
    return true;
   }
  },
  error: function (data) {

   MessageBoxError('Error');
  }
 });      
}
```

Second function that should run after first function returns true is:

```js
function saveOrEditQuote(status, id) {
  if(checkIfCompleted()) {  
    
    //my code here - it's long
     return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Just call  `saveOrEditQuote` in the else block of the ajax success function.

Comment: I call `saveOrEditQuote` on click of some buttons and I pass in it different parameters. If I call it in else, I can't pass these different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is asynchronous, try using callbacks like this

```
function checkIfCompleted(callback) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: Base_URL + "/offers/" + 'checkIfQuoteIsComplete',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "offer_id": offer_id                
        },

        success: function (data) {
            if(data === 'notcompleted') {
                $("#NotCompleteQuotes").modal();    
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {

            MessageBoxError('Error');
        }
    });      
}
```

then

```
function saveOrEditQuote(status, id) {
  checkIfCompleted(function(){
    // will be done only on success
    //my code here - it's long
        return false;
  })
}
```

Explanation:

A callback is simply another argument, the difference is that it is a function, not for example an integer. By using them you can make sure some block of code is called only after something. They're really helpful for actions that take some time (like requests, jquery animations, timeouts).

Comment: I think it works. I tested now. What does `callback` does?

Comment: I've updated the answer, hope it'll help you understand

Comment: Thank you! It means that when in else we call `callback();` - `saveOrEditQuote(status, id)` runs

Comment: Almost: `saveOrEditQuote` calls `checkIfCompleted` and passes a function (callback) as an argument to it. Now inside the `checkIfCompleted` function you call the argument function only when all your conditions are met. Try using a javascript debugger and see what happens step by step :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pass in the second callback function `saveOrEditQuote()` into the body of the success callback. You'll need be careful to declare that function in the right scope, because the success callback will be a different scope than `checkIfCompleted`.

Also, often the success argument `data` will be an array of objects and strings so `data === 'notcompleted'` may be comparing an array to a string.

```
function checkIfCompleted (){
  var success = saveOrEditQuote;
  $.ajax({ ... }).success(function(data){ success(true); })
}

function saveOrEditQuote(isCompleted){...};
```

Comment: Yes, but it has to be in separate function, because I call it several times dependent of which button is clicked and I pass different parameters.

Comment: you don't have to declare the function within `checkIfCompleted` you just have to pass that function as a variable. Functions are first class objects in JS and can be saved and passed around as variables. If your doing object oriented style you would do `var success = this.saveOrEditQuote;` if your doing a more functional style you would just reference the function via `var success = saveOrEditQuote;`.

Comment: Call `saveOrEditQuote` from the callback. In stead of calling saveOrEditQuote directly call the checkIfCompleted and have that function's callback call the function.

Comment: I don't understand it and how to do it.